# Timespan contains leapyear

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan, leap-year

I have 2 dates, a start (1/1/15) an end (31/12/16)

I need to calculate an amount per day from a total amount (20,000) and a annual amount based on 365 days,

I'm using Timespan to get the days between start and end dates, but in this case it returns 731 (365 + 366) as 2006 is a leap year,

but what I need is to get 730 without the leap day, is there any way of doing this

Thanks
Aj

Comment: You can check if your dates contain leap year if thats the case then substract that many days from the count.

Comment: but it I have a range between 2015, to 2025, both 2016 and 2020 are years, I wanted to avoid a looping though each year

Comment: Are those dates always from 1st Jan to 31st Dec? Because if so, the answer is surely just `int days = 365 * (endYear - startYear + 1);`

Comment: Those leapy ears are very annoying!

Comment: If you're dividing annual amounts into days, but omitting the leap day, your sums are not going to add up at the end of the... day (ha!). It would be like calculating a monthly amount, but insisting that all months have 28 days - months and years are measures of time that are inherently variable in the quantity of days they contain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps there is a more efficient approach but this works as expected:

```
public static int DaysDiffMinusLeapYears(DateTime dt1, DateTime dt2)
{
    DateTime startDate = dt1 <= dt2 ? dt1.Date : dt2.Date;
    DateTime endDate = dt1 <= dt2 ? dt2.Date : dt1.Date;
    int days = (endDate - startDate).Days + 1;

    int daysDiff = Enumerable.Range(0, days)
        .Select(d => startDate.AddDays(d))
        .Count(day => day.Day != 29 || day.Month != 2);
    return daysDiff;
}
```

Your sample:

```
int days = DaysDiffMinusLeapYears(new DateTime(15, 1, 1), new DateTime(16,12,31));
```

Result: 730

Comment: I think that the "+ 1" is critical. Perhaps you can explain a bit more about that and give an example without leap year that is correct.

Comment: @MareInfinitus: that's just to include the end-date in the calculation, otherwise it wiould be excluded. However, currently i'm not sure if this answer is useful since `(dt2-dt1).Days` also returns 730, so i don't understand the question anymore.

Comment: Yes, but that should be made visible to the user here. In a more mathematical notation it is the range [startdate, enddate[ so, you have to add. This is the crucial point in your solution.

Comment: This works! thank you very much, I was in the processing of looping the each year in range, and the messing around to check if the start and end was before or after the leap day, it was get big and messy, thank you very much